# ExtJs обновление хранилища

Tags: extjs

В ExtJs обновляю хранилище, и после обновления должна выполнится функция:

```
this.getClsTree().getStore().load()
```

Как можно узнать что store загрузилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще может зависить от версии ExtJS, неплохо бы её указать. Должно работать вот так:

```
grid.store.on('load', function(store, records, options) {
  // Ваш код
}, grid);
```

Comment: спасибо. Все работает!